# Mem leak in image loader

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk

I have a function for loading GdkPixbufAnimation from stream.

```
GdkPixbufAnimation* load_image_from_stream(GInputStream* input_stream, GCancellable* generator_cancellable)
{ 
   GError** error; 
 gboolean res;
 gssize n_read;
 guchar buffer[65535];

 GdkPixbufAnimation* animation;
 GdkPixbufLoader*    loader;

 loader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new();

 res = TRUE;

 while (1)
 {
      n_read = g_input_stream_read (input_stream, buffer, sizeof (buffer), generator_cancellable, error);

   if (n_read < 0)
   {
    res = FALSE;
    error = NULL; 
    g_object_unref(loader);
      break;
   }

   if (n_read == 0)
   {
      break;
    g_object_unref(loader);
   }

   if (!gdk_pixbuf_loader_write (loader, buffer, n_read, error))
   {
    res = FALSE;
    error = NULL;
    g_object_unref(loader);
    break;
   }
 }

 if (!gdk_pixbuf_loader_close (loader, error)) 
 {
  res = FALSE;
  error = NULL;
  return;
 }

 animation = NULL;

 if (res) 
 {
  animation = gdk_pixbuf_loader_get_animation(loader);

  if (animation)
  {
   g_object_ref (animation);
      g_object_unref(loader);
  }
 }

 return animation;
}
```

Try to call this functio so:

```
void loading(JobParam* param)
{   
    GInputStream* input_stream;
    input_stream = g_file_read(param->file, param->generator_cancellable, NULL);
    param->animation = load_image_from_stream(G_INPUT_STREAM(input_stream), param->generator_cancellable);  

    g_input_stream_close(input_stream, param->generator_cancellable, NULL);
    g_object_unref (input_stream);
}
```

But when i try to call this function i have mem leak. Why? What's wrong in function implementation?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Are statements in `if` block in right order?

```
 if (n_read == 0)
   {
      break;
      g_object_unref(loader);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

- Your indentation (or lack thereof) makes the code impossible to read. Fix that, and the errors will probably be more obvious.
- You have unreachable code in `if (n_read == 0)`, right after that break statement.
- You appear to be inconsistent in free-ing loader.
- `error` in never initialized, but is passed to `gdk_pixbuf_loader_new`.

Answer (score 3):

After the condition
    if (n_read == 0)
You have provided a break first. Hence the loaded pixbuff is not freed. So you are getting a memory leak.

Additional points:

You pass a double pointer namely `error` to the function

```
g_input_stream_read
```

This pointer will have the error code and error string loaded into it if there is a error in the API. Please check it before assigning that to NULL. You can probably check the structure definition of GError here. [GError](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Error-Reporting.html#GError)
Please check the value of code and message to get description on the error.

This has to be done for all the other API calls as well.
Hope that helps.